# the tkinter root window will not show up until the connection to the server has been lost

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tkinter

I am using socket and tkinter with a client and server. The server is supposed to send messages to the client which will be added to a listbox and displayed to the user as the messages are received in real time. However, the root window will not show up until the connection to the server has been lost (i.e. the server window has been closed). The messages still appear in the listbox when the root window *does* appear, though just not while there is a connection.

Here is the server:

```
import socket
import sys


#create a tcp/ip socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))

#bind the socket to the port
server_address = (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 8000)
print('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.bind((socket.gethostname(),8000))

#listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(2)

while True:
    #wait for connection
    print('waiting for a connection')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print('connection from', client_address)

        host_name=socket.gethostname()
        h=("connected to: "+host_name).encode()
        connection.sendall(h)
        while True:
            print("enter a message")
            m=input().encode()
            connection.sendall(m)

    finally:
        #end the communication
        connection.close()
```

and here is the client:

```
import socket
import sys
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst


#create a tcp/ip socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#connect the socket to the server's port
server_address = ("10.62.78.168", 8000)

p=('connecting to {} port {}'.format(*server_address))

sock.connect(server_address)

root=Tk()
root.title("client")

log=tkst.ScrolledText(root,width=100)
log.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

log.insert(END,p)

try:

    while True:

        p=(sock.recv(1024)).decode()
        m=("\n<Server> "+p)
        log.insert(END,m)

finally:
    print('closing socket')
    sock.close()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the client connects to the socket, it calls the server's  while loop. As you can see that loop won't stop until something stops it from inside. Since there's nothing that terminates it, it will only break when exceptions occur i.e. the connection fails/drops.

Only at this moment Python will proceed further and execute the lines where you create a window.

If you want the two thing to happen simultaneously you may want to have a look at [Threads](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm):

```
 thread.start_new_thread(connect_to_server);
```

Where `connect_to_server()` will be a function you define to connect and read data from the socket.

In this way the while loop will run on a separate thread while the main one will proceed to create the window.

Answer (score 0):

The window won't appear until `mainloop` is called, and you have an infinite loop running before `mainloop`. The solution is to move the code that reads from the socket into a thread so that it doesn't block the GUI. You will then need to use a thread-safe queue to communication between the worker thread and the GUI thread.